# redundant "default" window in an OS X app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xib

I am trying to create a **simple** test app. My goal is a single window with a button. Instead I get a "default" window opened in parallel with mine. If I delete all source code, the default window appears anyway. I use UIBuilder. How should `AppDelegate.m` look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the `.xib` file?

Comment: In my `xib` there is a window with a subview "button". Exactly how it should be, judging by UIBuilder.

Comment: Yup; sounds right to me.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a second window in the xib?  It might not be visible when you click on the xib in Xcode; not all UI elements in a nib are visible all the time.  (You can click on the close box of the window you created in the xib to see what I mean; it will close and no longer be visible, but it still exists in the nib and will load at app launch.)  You will need to look in the "outline view" list of objects in the nib, in the pane on the left side of the xib editor, to see whether another window exists in the nib that is not presently open in UIBuilder.

Comment: In addition I checked in the xml view. Not a thing.

Comment: I suspect i was supposed to attach the window to something, so that they became one, but i did not